# Unable to load in Excel from Power Query

Tags: excel, office365, powerquery

I use Excel 365 + Power Query (PQ): I created a query under PQ I manage to update it in PQ but when I want to load it in Excel it takes 15 minutes to run to finally fall into error

[error in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlxjb.png)

In other forums I have been told:

- That under PQ the query displays the first 999 lines
- Disable background refresh
- Avoid "select *"
- Enable fast charging

I did all of this without success. Can an Excel setting to increase the turnaround time?
I specify that the result of the query is more than 30,000 lines and this one works very well when the result is much less important.
If you have an idea, I'm interested :)

I did a google translation from French to English so I don't know if it's translated correctly ... sorry

Thank you !

Comment: PQ can use a lot of memory. Try to filter your data in an early step of your query and try again. If it flow without problems change the filter so you get a higher count of rows....
hard to say whats the problem if we not know what you are doing in/with the query.

Comment: I managed to load my result.

My query contains temporary tables and I don't know why but when PQ runs them it triples the rows (if you have the answer)
So, I isolated my tables (and that explains why Excel cannot load all the rows) to remove the duplicates and now it works :)